# Python + nose: make assertions about logged text?

Tags: python, testing, logging, nose

Is there some simple way of capturing and making assertions about logged messages with `nose`?

For example, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
cook_eggs()
assert_logged("eggs are ready!")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a custom handler which can check for the message being sent through logging. The [BufferingHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#memoryhandler) is a perfect match for this job.

You might also want to attach in your test the handler to any logger you are using in your code, such as `logging.getLogger('foo').addHandler(...)`. You could eventually attach the handler in the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods of your test case.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

class AssertingHandler(logging.handlers.BufferingHandler):

    def __init__(self,capacity):
        logging.handlers.BufferingHandler.__init__(self,capacity)

    def assert_logged(self,test_case,msg):
        for record in self.buffer:
            s = self.format(record)
            if s == msg:
                return
        test_case.assertTrue(False, "Failed to find log message: " + msg)


def cook_eggs():
    logging.warn("eggs are ready!")


import unittest

class TestLogging(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        asserting_handler = AssertingHandler(10)
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(asserting_handler)
        cook_eggs() 
        asserting_handler.assert_logged(self,"eggs are ready!")
        logging.getLogger().removeHandler(asserting_handler)


unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what "Mock Objects" are for.

You can use a mock version of logging which will properly buffer the log messages so that you can later make assertions about them.

Comment: Alright, so how do I correctly mock the `logging` module? I want to mock calls to, eg, `logging.warn(...)` and `logging.getLogger("foo").warn(...)`?

Comment: (obviously I can figure out where each individual bit of code is grabbing a reference to a logger, then override that reference… But I'm hoping there's a simpler way)

Comment: @David Wolever.  Mock `logging` -- the module.  Replace it with an object of a class that has the relevant API -- `getLogger` and some mock `Logger` class.  There are tools to help with this.  http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/.

Comment: But if I was to mock the logging module, I would need to do that before any tests start (ie, to make sure that `import logging` will return my logging module)… No? And, short of writing a Nose plugin or sticking something in the `__init__` of each test package, I'm not aware of any way to do that… Am I missing something?

Comment: @David Wolever. Here's where the phrase "dependency injection" becomes so very important.  A module that magically imports and instantiates things is hard to test.  A class that is carefully configured before use is much, much easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Just FWIW, in datalad project we needed similar functionality but also to just swallow the logs (and possibly introspect).  So here came the solution -- swallow_logs context handler: https://github.com/datalad/datalad/blob/master/datalad/utils.py#L296 (currently at b633c9da46ab9cccde3d4767928d167a91857153). So now in the test we do smth like

```
def test_swallow_logs():
    lgr = logging.getLogger('datalad')
    with swallow_logs(new_level=9) as cm:
        eq_(cm.out, '')
        lgr.log(8, "very heavy debug")
        eq_(cm.out, '')  # not even visible at level 9
        lgr.log(9, "debug1")
        eq_(cm.out, 'debug1\n')  # not even visible at level 9
        lgr.info("info")
        eq_(cm.out, 'debug1\ninfo\n')  # not even visible at level 9
```